# How can we remove the horizontal line in `moderncv` header (not in the sections)?

Tags: moderncv, rules

I am using this template

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle[left]{casual}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries}
\moderncvcolor{grey} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\firstname{First} 
\familyname{Last} 
\title{Title}
\address{address 1}{address 2}
\mobile{0000000}
\email{email}

\begin{document}
    
\makecvtitle

content
    
\end{document}
```

The output is nice and simple like this
[image]

Is there a way to remove that horizontal line in the header?

I saw something similar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61816/horizontal-line-in-moderncvtheme-classic) but not sure if that works here. I also found this
`{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%` [moderncvheadii.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadii.sty) but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle[left]{casual}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries}
\moderncvcolor{grey} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%Add this package:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\firstname{First} 
\familyname{Last} 
\title{Title}
\address{address 1}{address 2}
\mobile{0000000}
\email{email}

%Add this command
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}{}{}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

content
    
\end{document}
```

We are replacing the command already found by you with nothing using xpatch package